# VB net forearch into one text

Tags: vb.net

I made an app in vb.net which show the interface's mac address.

```
Dim computerProperties As IPGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
If nics Is Nothing OrElse nics.Length < 1 Then
    Console.WriteLine("  No network interfaces found.")
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each adapter As NetworkInterface In nics
    If adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.Length > 1 Then
        If adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.Contains("000") Then
        Else
            MsgBox(adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString())
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I want to put the mac addresses into one string like this
"00ffg344f2-33f5h6g3-...."
How can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim L As New List(Of String)
Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
If nics Is Nothing OrElse nics.Length < 1 Then
    Console.WriteLine("  No network interfaces found.")
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 0 To nics.Count - 1
    If nics(i).GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.Length > 1 Then If Not nics(i).GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.Contains("000") Then L.Add(nics(i).GetPhysicalAddress.ToString())
Next
MsgBox(String.Join("-", L.ToArray()))
```

Try to use the previous code , I think that's what exactly you want.
Another shorter solution:

```
Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
If nics Is Nothing OrElse nics.Length < 1 Then
    Console.WriteLine("  No network interfaces found.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim OutputArr() As String = nics.Cast(Of NetworkInterface).Select(Function(x) x.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString()).Where(Function(x) x.Length > 1).ToArray()
MsgBox(String.Join("-", OutputArr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

For Each adapter As NetworkInterface In nics

    If adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.Length > 1 Then

        If Not adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.Contains("000") Then

            sb.Append( adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString() )
            sb.Append( vbCrLf )
        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox( sb.ToString() )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is it possible to make it with "-" ? Because after its appended, I will post it to a serverside and handle it with php, and in the database I want to separate the different HWID- MAC's with "-".
Thats why I asked. :) I have made the same before, but I removed the appent part.

Comment: @RichárdKiss Follow my code and see where you could add `sb.Append( "-" )`. It's very easy to understand.

Comment: Yep, but If I add it I will have one more after the last mac address. Thats my problem. :c :) Here is it: http://snag.gy/z2eCQ.jpg

Comment: You could always remove that using various methods from the String class. `TrimEnd()` or `SubString()` are two useful methods.

Comment: Use a List(Of String) and add the strings there at the end use String.Join with the separator required